# hide an element that was loaded from another loaded element

Tags: jquery

In my main page I have a "music" button, it loads music.txt

script.js

```
$("#music").load("music.txt");
$(document).on('click', '.song',  function (){ 
    var songDetails= $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
    $(this).load(songDetails+'.txt'); 
});
```

music.txt:

```
<span class="song"> bl </span>
```

so **music.txt** loads list of songs. And ach song is listed as `<li>`.

for example, in **hotelcalifornia.txt**:

```
<div class="details">
Eagles, 4:30, Sony Music
<span class="minimize"> Minimize </span> 
</div>
```

now, when I click, I get song details. But I cannot minimize/disappear it.

```
$(document).on('click', '.minimize',  function () { $('.details').hide(); });
```

doesn't work.

Comment: not sure, but shouldn't that `.on(...` be `.delegate(...` ?

Comment: Try like this on your page load $('.minimize').on('click',function(){Your code});

Comment: tried both no success. The problem is with hiding .details. I can hide .song there, but not .details.

Comment: What is prompts if you write alert($('.details').text()); on click of minimize?

Comment: good point @KD. It gives hotelcalifornia.txt .

Comment: OK I figured out. $(document).on('click', '.song',  function () {}); is causing pronlem. I put some control statement, so it is either in that one, or the the other $(document).on one.

Answer (score 1):

replace this:

```
$('.details').hide();
```

with this in your current code as posted:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
```

Comment: actually I had tried that too, it does not work, thanks though.